# Why is this SHM derivation the way it is?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, differential-equations

[image: This is a derivation for simple harmonic motion equation]

I know four different forms in which an SHM can be represented after solving the differential and taking the superposition,

- $A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$
- $A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$
- $A\cos(\omega t-\phi)$
- $A\sin(\omega t-\phi)$

where $A$ is the amplitude, $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $\phi$ is the phase at $t=0$.

In the above image, they took $B$ as negative in order to arrive at $A\cos(\omega t +\epsilon)$. If I already knew I wanted $A\cos(\omega t +\epsilon)$ or $A\cos(\omega t -\epsilon)$ as the solution then I would have decided how to modify $B$ in order to get my answer, but if I'm deriving it for the first time then how would I know whether to take B as positive or negative.
Can't they just take it as positive and end up with $\cos(\omega t-\phi)$. How is the process justified here?

*Note:-* Here $\phi$ and $\epsilon$ represent the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but let me give it a shot. Many times in physics, I often encounter a lot of trial and error functions and the rule of thumb my professors say is if it fits the boundary conditions, it is correct.

An example I can give is solutions to laplace's equation where more often than not, after using separation of variables, we often end up with an equations that looks something like this:

$$\frac{\partial ^2 X(x)}{\partial x^2} = -k^2 x$$

Even in cases like that, we have a problem, there is more than one solution to this equation where:

$$X(x) = A \sin(kx) + B\cos(kx) \tag{1}$$ 
$$X(x) = A \sinh(kx) + B\cosh(kx) \tag{2}$$ 
$$X(x) = A \exp(kx) + B\exp(-kx) \tag{3} $$

all $(1), (2), (3)$ are solutions, so how do we know which is the right one?

It **needs to fit the boundary condition**

if we already know that X(x) must tend to zero at infinity, then we would obviously pick (3) as the correct solution.

So going back to your original question, there's nothing wrong with taking $B$ instead of $-B$, however after imposing boundary conditions, you will realize your B would be less than 0 while the "B" used in the "-B" is positive.

B is just a constant so don't worry too much about it!

Comment: (1) Do you mean $\partial^2_x X= -k^2 X$?. (2) Your solutions should be in terms of $kx$ not $x$. (3) If you do mean the first order equation then only 3 is a solution, if you mean -k^2 then only 1 is. I would write it with +k^2 and then 2 and 3 are both solutions.

Comment: @jacob1729 ah yes sorry! i have edited it, was typing it in a rush